How to switch from cloud run domain mappings to custom domains google cloud load balancer
My cloud run instance is currenlty managed by cloud run domain mappings, I was hoping to switch this over to custom domain google cloud load balancer.  I went through the steps and added the integration in my cloud run instance and everything seemed to work, However the SSL certificate status is PROVISIONING and when I look up certificate details under Load Balancing it states it is FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE for the domain.  I created an A record in my DNS for the new load balancer but did not touch the existing 4 DNS A records previously created by cloud run domain mappings which had me add 4 A and 4 AAAA records to my DNS.  Do I need to delete these records in my DNS management in order for the new load balancer to work?  Also is there a way I can do this without downtime for my application by possibly using a subdomain and somehow point the load balancer to use that first?  I'm not sure any help is appreciated.
On this documentation page it states

DNS must not resolve to any other IP address than the load balancer's.
For example, if an A record resolves to the correct load balancer, but
the AAAA resolves to something else, the domain status is
FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE.

Does this mean I need to delete the existing A and AAAA records in my DNS?  also the load balancer only had me create and A record and not a AAAA record


Did you validate your domain with Google Cloud (add a TXT entry in your registrar)? If so, and if you have registered your load balancer HTTPS (s is important here!) IP in your registrar, as a A entry, it should work (it take between 15 and 60 minutes to detect the registrar update and generate automatically a certificate). However, if your registrar already had a A entry and you changed it for your Cloud Run, you must wait the end of the TTL (sometime 24h) to let the cache expire and propagate the new configuration.

@guillaumeblaquiere yes I have a TXT starting with google-site-verification already from my previous cloud run mappings, haven't changed that and under load balancing in network services I have two entries one for http and one for https, as I stated In my domain registrar I had 4 previous A records and AAAA records from the cloud run domain mappings the load balancer integration had me add another A record so in total I have 6 A records - 4 from cloud run domain mappings, 1 from load balancer and one parked one from go daddy - also tried creating a subdomain one as well

Does it make sense to just delete the existing cloud run domain mappings? And keep the Custom domains (GCLB) Because right now there are two mappings pointing to the same domain

Indeed, in your registrar, you must remove all the other A entry at the root level @ to avoid the confusion. And also remove the cloud run domain mapping at the root level (if you use subdomain, it should continue to work)

Thanks for you response and help @guillaumeblaquiere - essentially it seems like I would need to bring the site down - I am testing adding a subdomain A record in my registrar and also adding that route in my load balancer - is that a good way to test it will work before I delete the existing A records and my cloud run domain mapping - are there any good articles or resources on how to do this, I just don't want to risk a lot of downtime

for example when I use https://dnspropagation.net/ and type in my subdomain it points to the load balancing IP address so I know that it has propagated in my registrar and I added a routing rule for my subdomain under my custom domains in load balancing, but it doesn't seem to be working currently, not sure how long it needs - but rather test it first before shutting everything down

I never get this issue. I think you have to remove all the A and AAAA address from your domain registrar. To avoid downtime, I'm not sure it's possible with that configuration. A solution would be to generate a certificate on our side and upload it to the load balancer (instead of auto provisioning). Like this you could have the 2 configuration (Cloud Run mapping & Load balancer mapping) working together and then stop one without disturbing the other.

In case you wish to have zero downtime, there is the possibility to keep the old certificate before it expires, then create a new one and update your configuration to take the new certificate, and then delete the old cert. And by this method you could avoid the downtime.
Also for the certificate provisioning error you can try removing the current mapping in the google cloud run. In cloudflare, change the proxy status of the DNS record from proxied to DNS only and try to add mapping again in google cloud run.

If you are managing and hosting your DNS records for your domain via GCP, you can refer to this. Additionally you can also look at this for similar kinds of issues.

@guillaumeblaquiere - I updated the DNS records and it's been an hour or so and the site is broken, I was trying to avoid this at all costs - It's so frustrating - there should be simple way of doing this my certificate still reads FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE and my site is completely down, ugh I think I'm going to back to custom domain or even switch services away from google, what a nightmare, It's not like I can refresh the status - I have no idea if it's even trying to still provision it - like waiting for you have no control over

It's been over two hours so I'm going to delete the integration and just start over - what a cluster F - I will try one more time if not I will go back using custom domain mapping and use Cloudflare instead

Well, this was a frustrating process but was able to get load balancer working essentially by deleting the existing integration and deleting the custom run domain mappings and starting over.  Steps I took were to create a new cloud run  Integration Custom domains - Google Cloud Load Balancing and when that was provisioning it game me an IP address to update my Domain Registrar and so I needed to delete all other A and AAAA records, essentially brining my site down but it didn't take that long to provision a new certificate about an hour so I did late at night
On my first attempt - I had already deleted all A and AAAA records and was waiting for it to retry provisioning the certificate because like I said it was still provisioning but had a FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE status - but it didn't seem to try re-provisioning which was frustrating as I couldn't tell what it was doing. I waited two hours and nothing happened.
I even tried after about an hour creating a need certificate within the load balancing console but since I had no control over the original certificate (meaning I could not delete) I don't think it like having two certificates with the same domain.  I had some success updating a subdomain on my registrar and creating a certificate for that subdomain in the load balancer and then routing all traffic back to that subdomain, but I couldn't figure out how to exactly switch from subdomain to regular domain easily in the same load balancer.  Sigh so in total of 3 hours the site was down.
I'm exactly not sure like a commentator mentioned if it's possible to switch without any any downtime, so my recommendation if you're going to do this is to expect downtime and you can start the integration but make sure you immediately update your DNS records as soon as the load balancer integration gives you your new IP address.  It seemed to update within an hour from updating my DNS records.
Thanks to all who commented and made suggestions appreciate the feedback.
